# How to override wp-admin styling

Tags: php, wp-admin, templates, jquery-ui

How can I copy the default styling for the admin and tell wordpress to use custom style instead of the default? Basically I want to change the colour and font without having to use !important syntax to force Wordpress to use it.

Comment: Couldn't you just enqueue your own style sheet in the admin and override the CSS you need to?

Comment: @WilliamJerome If you have found the answer, share it as an answer to your question, so others can benefit.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by @Fusion, this has changed beginning with version 5. In order to override admin styles for 5.*, you need a hook in `functions.php`, something like this:

```php
function custom_admin() {
    $url = get_settings('siteurl');
    $url = $url . '/wp-content/themes/my-theme/wp-admin.css';
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . $url . '" />';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'custom_admin')
```

Sources:
[Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes)
[isitwp Snippet](https://www.isitwp.com/custom-admin-css/)

Please note the the **isitwp Snippet** erroneously mixes html entitites with angle brackets. You should use angle brackets not entitieis.

Comment: Please use `get_option()` instead of `get_settings()` as that has been deprecated since 2.1.1! In fact, the "modern" best practice would be `$url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/wp-admin.css';`

Answer (score 1):

Enqueue custom admin CSS file (custom-admin.css) in your WordPress backend using below function:

```
add_action('admin_print_styles', 'custom_admin_css');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_admin_css');

function custom_admin_css() {
    if (is_admin()) {
        wp_enqueue_style("custom-admin-css", get_bloginfo('template_directory'). "/custom_admin.css", false, false, "all");
    }
}
```

Hope this works..!!

Comment: In current 5.* version of Wordpress it "works", but if you want to add custom CSS of Wordpres's admins interface (for example a purple button), you will not move anywhere. Wordpress loads all the native admin-css as the last element of the page - meaning, that all your custom CSS will be overriden.

Answer (score 0):

In **WordPress 5.x** you can use the following hooks to add CSS to either the admin pages or the post edit page.

`enqueue_block_editor_assets` to add your own styles to the Gutenberg page

`admin_enqueue_scripts` to add your own styles to the admin pages

You can add the hooks in your `functions.php` theme file.

Comment: According to the [docs][1] `admin_print_styles` should not be used to enqueue styles to the admin page. Use `admin_enqueue_scripts` instead (both for scripts and styles).


  [1]: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_print_styles/